# SolR Delta Import parameter

Tags: solr, parameters

I'm trying to use parameter (id) in my solr delta import :

my dataimport.xml

```
<document name="products">
    <entity name="products" rootEntity="true" query="SELECT * FROM products" deltaQuery="SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ${dih.delta.id}" transformer="script:addValue">
        ....
```

The full import work correctly, but ${dih.delta.id} return nothing ...

My request : http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=delta-import&id=8

Someone could explain me we're i'm wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just replace ${dih.delta.id} with  ${dih.request.id} and now it's work !